# "It was still bright/light outside." Is one of these incorrect?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

If I want to say it's still somewhat early in the evening and it's not so dark outside so that you can still see things quite clearly almost like during daytime, which of the following sentences would be a better fit?

> 1. It was still **bright** outside.
> 2. It was still **light** outside.

I was told that one of them is incorrect, but both of them seem right to me.

Comment: Whoever told you is wrong. They don't mean the same thing, and only (2) is idiomatic, but they're both grammatical, and as correct as they can be.

Comment: Oh, thanks John! If what I really mean to say is that it's still kinda early in the evening and it's not so dark outside and you can still see things almost like during daytime, which sentence would be a better fit?

Comment: Oh, I'd say (2) in that case. Maybe _still a bit light_ for emphasis. _Bright_ would mean considerably, um, brighter; also lighter.

Comment: Thank you very much, John. Now I understand the difference.

Comment: After _still a bit light_ one passes over to _not quite dark yet_, when color vision ceases and you only get b/w. When that goes it's dark.

Comment: There is no harm in expressing what you need so you could say "It was still light outside **and visibility was good**." - this would emphasises the sentiment that you describe.

Answer (score 2):

The expression *still light outside* has existed for long. And it *is* grammatical. 
See: [Different 'Light' Usages (1)](http://www.english-test.net/esl/learn/english/grammar/ai719/esl-test.php)

From the Harper's Magazine, [Vol 149](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=lmMQAAAAIAAJ&q=%22still%20light%20outside%22&dq=%22still%20light%20outside%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xQOXUeXOKIP5rQfRxYHwDA&redir_esc=y) [**1924**]

> And now, with the window shuttered and the door closed, she could not tell when it was dark. She could pretend it was **still light outside**. But the village was quiet, quiet.

Sir John Alexander Hammerton *[The Masterpiece Library of Short Stories](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=cqwLAAAAMAAJ&q=%22still%20light%20outside%22&dq=%22still%20light%20outside%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xQOXUeXOKIP5rQfRxYHwDA&redir_esc=y)* [**1920**]

> … up the slippery winding stairs. Then he sighed still more deeply and went in again. Though it was **still light outside**, the basement was clothed in a dark blue half-light, so that all that could be seen …

*[Stop the Clock](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=ZB0DAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA304&dq=%22still%20light%20outside%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ewGXUZK_IsiGrAer1oH4Ag&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22still%20light%20outside%22&f=false)* Deborah Paul writing in the Indianapolis Monthly Mar **2007**

> When we turn the clocks forward this month, daylight will begin to extend longer and longer until summer comes and before we know it, it's nearly 10 p.m. and **still light outside**. This just isn't natural.

Ronald Schmidt, *[The Undelivered](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=4Ud4O1FL6TIC&pg=PA152&dq=%22still%20light%20outside%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ewGXUZK_IsiGrAer1oH4Ag&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22still%20light%20outside%22&f=false)* [**2008**]

> … it is now almost 10:00 pm. However, it was **still light outside**. He has never seen the so-called Midnight Sun before.

However, it seems more of a literary and colloquial use rather than formal.

[*Still light outside at 9pm*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBPouzpTDzo) (garvolinda on YouTube 0:45)

Has *light* in this sense gained [greater acceptance and usage of late](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=still%20bright%20outside,still%20light%20outside&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) over *bright*?
[image]

Comment: Possibly regional to US upper midwest.

Answer (score 1):

The first one would be a more frequently used and seen one. Or you can always say "It's dimmer than the day outside." or just "It's dim outside". The second one is grammatically correct too . So, no worries and just stick to what you prefer. Unless, you are worried that the other party's understanding of vocabulary is not as good as yours, then you should stick to the first one to avoid any misunderstanding. :)

Comment: _Dusk_ would be preferable to _dim_ in the evening; I tend to shift over to _still dark_ or _still a bit dark_ in the morning, but that's just the force of the temporal metaphor rotating around.

Comment: I think the relative frequency will depend on where you are -- in KY I hear "light outside" more often than "bright".

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard “dim outside,” and while people do talk of a “bright summer day,” that's something you'd hear around noon, not in the evening. I'd prefer “getting dark” or “light outside.” That's both for Detroit and the San Francisco Bay Area.